# Calendar not showing up using simple version of datepicker (not popup version) with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I tried adding the simple version of bootstrap datepicker for angularjs to my project. The other pieces of it appear fine but not the calendar. I added the html code like this:

```
<td>
          <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
            <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>
            <h4>Inline</h4>
            <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
              <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></uib-datepicker>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="setDate(2009, 7, 24)">2009-08-24</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" uib-tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
          </div>
        </td>
```

And the js code was added to a component like this:
    angular.module('components.datepicker').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

```
$scope.clear = function() {
  $scope.dt = null;
};

$scope.options = {
  customClass: getDayClass,
  minDate: new Date(),
  showWeeks: true
};

// Disable weekend selection
function disabled(data) {
  var date = data.date,
    mode = data.mode;
  return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
}

$scope.toggleMin = function() {
  $scope.options.minDate = $scope.options.minDate ? null : new Date();
};

$scope.toggleMin();

$scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
  $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
};

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
var afterTomorrow = new Date(tomorrow);
afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
$scope.events = [
  {
    date: tomorrow,
    status: 'full'
  },
  {
    date: afterTomorrow,
    status: 'partially'
  }
];

function getDayClass(data) {
  var date = data.date,
    mode = data.mode;
  if (mode === 'day') {
    var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
      var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
        return $scope.events[i].status;
      }
    }
  }

  return '';
}
```

});

I also injected ui.bootstrap into my app.js like this:
    angular.module("components.datepicker", ["ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap"]);

I added the scripts to my index.html ike this:

I have tried a wide variety of things including using the popup version but the calendar never shows up in those either. I do have the latest version of angular. I do have the latest version of angular-animate. I am trying to include this datepicker in a pretty complex app and everything else the app works fine. Thanks for your help on this!